# determine $\mathbb E(X_1 \mid X_2)$ and $\mathbb V(X_1 \mid X_2)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $(X_1,X_2)$ be a normally distributed vector with $\mathbb E(X_1) = \frac14$, $\mathbb E(X_2) = 0$, $\mathbb V(X_1) = 1$, $\mathbb V(X_2) = \frac14$, $\operatorname{Cov}(X_1,X_2) = -\frac18$.

I want to determine $\mathbb E(X_1 \mid X_2)$ and $\mathbb V(X_1 \mid X_2)$.

I am not quite sure how to apply the definitions of conditional probability.

Comment: The information you have allows you to construct the joint probability.

Comment: Hint: Find $(a,b,c)$ such that $$X_1=aX_2+bX_3+c$$ where $X_3$ is standard normal independent of $X_2$ and deduce your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the approach in the comment by @Did,

Let $X_1 = aX_2 + bX_3 + c$ where $X_3 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $X_2$ is independent of $X_3$ we try to find $a, b, c$.

$$\operatorname{Cov}(X_1, X_2) = \frac{-1}{8} \implies  a\operatorname{Var}(X_2) = \frac{-1}{8}$$

> $$a = \frac{-1}{2}$$

$$E(X_1) = \frac{1}{4} \implies aE(X_2) + c = \frac{1}{4}$$

> $$c = \frac{1}{4}$$

$$\operatorname{Var}(X_1) = 1 \implies a^2\operatorname{Var}(X_2) + b^2 =  1$$

> $$ b = \frac{\sqrt{15}}{4}$$

Therefore, $X_1$ can now be written as,

> $$X_1 = \frac{-X_2}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{15}X_3}{4} + \frac{1}{4}$$

and $E(X_1\mid X_2), V(X_1\mid X_2)$ are,

> $$E(X_1\mid X_2) = \frac{-X_2}{2} + \frac{1}{4}, V(X_1\mid X_2) = \frac{15}{16}$$

Comment: Is there a name for this method, where you decompose $X_1$ in this sum?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for the edit. I will keep in mind about those latex commands in future.

Comment: @Did Can you please answer the comment by Pazu. Thanks.

Comment: It might not be clear that this trick only works for jointly normal variables.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}\newcommand{\v}{\operatorname{var}}\newcommand{\c}{\operatorname{cov}}$

I thought of posting an answer involving expectations and covariances, and someone has posted something along those lines, so I'll try a different way of looking at it. You have
$$
\rho = \operatorname{correlation}(X_1,X_2) = \frac{\c(X_1,X_2)}{\sqrt{\v(X_1)\v(X_2)}} = \frac{1/8}{\sqrt{1\cdot1/4}} = \frac 1 4.
$$
Suppose you know that the joint density is
$$
\text{constant} \times
      \exp\left(
        -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[
          \frac{(x_1-\frac 1 4)^2}{1/2} +
          \frac{(x_2-0)^2}{1} -
          \frac{2\rho(x_1-\frac 1 4)(x_2-0)}{(1/4)\cdot 1}
        \right]
      \right)
$$
Recall that the conditional density of $X_1$ given $X_2=x_2$ is a constant multiple of the expression above as a function of $x_1$ with $x_2$ fixed. And it will be a normal density, having its maximum at its expected value. The expression above has its maximum at the point where the quadratic polynomial inside the $\Big[\text{square brackets}\Big]$ has its minimum.
\begin{align}
& \frac{(x_1-\frac 1 4)^2}{1/2} + \frac{(x_2-0)^2} 1 - \frac{2\rho(x_1-\frac 1 4)(x_2-0)}{(1/4)\cdot 1} \\[10pt]
= {} & 2\left(x_1 - \frac 1 4\right)^2 - 2\left(x_1 - \frac 1 4 \right) x_2 + \cdots\cdots \\
& \quad \text{where “$\cdots\cdots$'' means terms not depending on $x_1$} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{(4x_1-1)^2} 8 - 2x_1x_2 + \cdots\cdots \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac 1 8 \left( (16x_1^2 - 8x_1 + 1) - 16 x_1 x_2 \right) + \cdots\cdots \\[10pt]
\propto {} & \underbrace{x_1^2 - \left( \frac 1 2 + x_2 \right)x_1 + \cdots\cdots = x_1^2 -\left( \frac 1 2 + x_2 \right) x_1 + \left( \frac{1+ 2x_2} 4 \right)^2 + \cdots\cdots}_{\Large\text{completing the square}} \\[12pt]
= {} & \left( x_1 - \frac{1+2x_2} 4 \right)^2 + \cdots.
\end{align}
We expect
$$
\left( x_1 - \text{something} \right)^2,
$$
where $\text{“something''}$ does not depend on $x_1,$ and we got $\text{“something''} = \dfrac{1+2x_2} 4.$ Therefore
$$
\E(X_1\mid X_2 = x_2) = \frac{1+2x_2} 4.
$$

**PS:** I now see that $\rho = \dfrac{-1} 4$ had a minus sign. So just change that in the appropriate places.

Comment: I think this is a better approach for me since I already determined the joint density function and I don't understand what kind of method is used in the other answer (that is why I consider this my prefered solution)

Comment: @Pazu : In some situations I consider methods like that in the other answer preferable, but if I posted something like that, I'd want to make it as simple as possible, and that would cost me some effort right now. But the sort of thing that is seen in the approach I used here is also something one should be aware of if one wants to understand the multivariate normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(X_1,X_2)$ is normally distributed, $$ c_1 X_1+c_2X_2 \overset{d}{=} \mu(c_1,c_2) + \sigma(c_1,c_2) W,\quad \forall c_1,c_2\in \mathbb{R}$$
where $$\mu(c_1,c_2) = \mathbb{E}[c_1 X_1+c_2X_2] = c_1 \mathbb{E}[X_1] + c_2\mathbb{E}[X_2],$$
$$\sigma(c_1,c_2)=\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}[c_1 X_1+c_2X_2]} = \sqrt{c_1^2\operatorname{Var}[ X_1] +c_2^2 \operatorname{Var}[X_2] + 2c_1c_2\operatorname{Cov}[X_1,X_2]},$$ and $W$ is a standard normal random variable.
Now, taking expected value conditioned on $X_2$ of above 
$$ c_1 \operatorname{E}[X_1\mid X_2] + c_2 X_2 = \mu(c_1,c_2) + \sigma(c_1,c_2)\operatorname{E}[W\mid X_2]$$
Similarly,
$$c_1^2\operatorname{Var}[X_1\mid X_2] = \sigma^2(c_1,c_2) \operatorname{Var}[W\mid X_2]$$
Let $c_{1*}, c_{2*}$ be values of $c_1,c_2$ such that $W $ is independent of $X_2$, equivalently, $\operatorname{E}[WX_2] = \operatorname{E}[W] \operatorname{E}[X_2]=0$. This can be done by multiplying the first equation by $X_2$ and taking expected values on both sides. Then, we have
$$\operatorname{E}[X_1\mid X_2] = \frac{\mu(c_{1*}, c_{2*}) - c_{2*}X_2}{c_{1*}}$$
and 
$$ \operatorname{Var}[X_1\mid X_2] = \frac{\sigma^2(c_{1*}, c_{2*})}{c_{1*}^2}$$

Comment: Does $ c_1 X_1+c_2X_2 \overset{d}{=} \mu(c_1,c_2) + \sigma(c_1,c_2) W, \forall c_1,c_2\in \mathbb{R}$ only hold for bivariate normal distributions?

Comment: No. This holds for all multivariate normal distribution. Alternatively, a collection of random variables is said to be jointly normal distributed if any linear combination of the variables is (univariate) normal distributed.